# Wordpress: Add post link to all images in post

Tags: wordpress

When the new media uploader was introduced back in WordPress 4, many awesome features were added that made adding images to your posts a whole lot easier. One thing that bugged me a little though I never really took the time to change was the default attachment display settings that appeared each time you opened the media uploader.

I need to change the `image_default_link_type` to post link like `www.domain.com/?p=234` not for attachment post or file

Can i to that

Comment: ehm ... pretty hard to read this question. But if I'm correct, all the images should link to the page you are already on?

Comment: but in my blog not have any link

Comment: Sorry, but I can't really help you if you don't speak some proper english.